# How to achieve internal service to service communication in Anthos multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

How to achieve internal service to service communication in Anthos multiple clusters Example
service A deployed in GKE cluster and service B deployed in AKS cluster, here how we can call service A from service B (internally) ?

Comment: how are you planning actually? multiple options possibly actually, you can peer the VPCs going with VPN option. Mesh option ref : https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/off-gcp-multi-cluster-setup

Comment: I want to ensure traffic should not exposed to public internet, how can we do it?

Comment: Have you checked this document on [Set up a multi cluster mesh on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/gke-install-multi-cluster).

Comment: @FariyaRahmat yes two clusters are two different network one in gcp one in aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Harsh Manver you can [set up a multi cluster mesh outside Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/off-gcp-multi-cluster-setup) to achieve internal service to service communication in Anthos multiple clusters.

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/multi-cloud-hybrid-mesh):

> The cluster's Kubernetes control plane address and the gateway address
> need to be reachable from every cluster in the mesh. The Google Cloud
> project in which GKE clusters are located should be allowed to create
> external load balancing types.
>
> We recommend that you use authorized networks and VPC firewall rules
> to restrict the access and  ensure traffic should not exposed to
> public internet